# How to get all the values from the deleted row into a column in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

TBL_EMPLOYEE

```
ID  NAME        SOURCE
1   SANDERS     OUTSOURCE
```

TBL_AUDIT

```
NAME    COLUMNNAMES COLUMNVALUES
```

On delete of employee from tbl_employee, I am trying to insert info into tbl_audit.

I am hard coding the values for tblname and columnnames, but I cannot figure out how to get all the values from the deleted row into the columnvalues column (comma delimited).

Any guidance would greatly be appreciated.

**example**:   employee 1 is deleted

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRIGGER_DELETE
ON tbl_employee
FOR DELETE
AS
 INSERT INTO tbl_audit  (tblName, columnNames, columnValues)
 VALUES 
 (
 'tbl_employee',
 'id, name, source',
 SELECT STUFF(select ',' + tbl_employee.id, tbl_employee.name, tbl_employee.source FROM DELETED WHERE tbl_employee.id IN(SELECT deleted.id FROM deleted)) 
 ) 
  WHERE tbl_employee.id IN(SELECT deleted.id FROM deleted)
```

Comment: Your example is not so clear,can you post what is that you are trying to do step by step and final output..Your title seems to be clear,but i assume it is `deleted row into a table` instead of `deleted row into a column `

Comment: For the life of me I cannot figure why everyone insists on using the nested selects, when they can simply select from `deleted`!!! Who is teaching the nested selects to everyone? We need to find that one and beat with a stick over the head.

Comment: One major challenge you are going to run into with this type of audit table is actually recovering the data. Consider how difficult this is going to be to put together a history of the table. Or the inevitable question from management "what did the entire table look like on a certain day". Your audit table is violating 1NF by shoving multiple values into a single column like this. It will render your auditing pretty much useless as you will find it nearly impossible to reassemble later.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sys.columns](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/get-table-column-names-list-in-sql-server.aspx) system view to fetch columns of a database table on SQL Server

```
SELECT Name FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = object_id('tblName')
```

My solution for changed data (updated or deleted) I once used [custom history tables for logging in SQL Server](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-trigger-sql-server-trigger-example-to-log-changes-history.aspx). Perhaps you can check that as well. But it requires one history table for your targeted source table for logging.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below trigger to insert into a seperate table

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.TriggerName ON dbo.TBL_EMPLOYEE
FOR UPDATE, DELETE
AS

DECLARE @Action CHAR(1)

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1  FROM Inserted)
BEGIN
    SET @Action = 'U'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @Action = 'D'
END

INSERT dbo.TBL_AUDIT
    (
        ID  
        ,[Name]
        ,[SOURCE]
        ,[Action]
    )
SELECT  
    ID  
    ,[Name]
    ,[SOURCE]
    ,@Action
FROM DELETED
GO
```